# chart.js charts wouldn't show or hide with Angular directives ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I have a chart which works properly when shown in a static manner.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
$scope.lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, chartConfig);
```

However, when I wrap it inside ng-show, as shown below, it stops rendering itself.

```
<div ng-show="output.showChart">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Somewhere in JS:

```
$scope.output.showChart = true;
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

Wrapping chart creation in **$timeout**(with default timeout of 0 ms) works:

---

**Long answer**:

$timeout with delay set to 0 removes the necessity to call $apply, because $timeout will trigger another $digest cycle of its own, which in turn will do all the necessary updating.

```
$scope.output.showChart = true;
$timeout(function(){
    if($scope.lineChart){
       $scope.lineChart.destroy();
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    $scope.lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, chartConfig);
});
```